# java.lang.NullPointerException when filling an array of objects

Tags: java

There's something I'm missing here. with this code I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Board board = new Board();
    board.Initialise();

}


public class Board {

private Obj[][] tableau;

public void Board() {

    tableau = new Obj[8][8];    
}

public void Fill_Board() {

    tableau[0][0]= new Obj('B');
    }
}
```

But with this other code I get no error. What I am doing wrong, and how to initialize properly this array of object?

```
public class Board {

private Obj[][] tableau = new Obj[8][8];

public void Board() {

}

public void Fill_Board() {

    tableau[0][0]= new Obj('B');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide us more context because you have a class Tab but you don't use it in main()

Comment: @TerraNova993 Why are you unformatting the edits people made to make your code readable?

Answer (score 2):

`Board()` ends up being a member function and not a constructor, and therefore never gets called. The problem is the `void` keyword, which needs to be removed:

```
public Board() { /* removed the `void' */
    tableau = new Obj[8][8];    
}
```

Comment: @Makoto: There clearly is (`Board board = new Board()`). What we're presented with is a snippet, and I suspect the fact that `Board()` seems to appear in `Tab` -- and not in `Board` -- is just an artefact of this being a snippet.

Comment: I **really** don't get the downvotes. I am starting to regret investing time into trying to help out.

Comment: sorry for this, this is just a snippet actually, I edited the code to rename the class properly.

Comment: Now it's right. At first there was no `Board` class. That's why you got my downvote. Now you got an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I get no error when I run this code (changing Obj to an actual class), perhaps you can provide a more concrete example with a main method of what you're trying to do?

If you're looking at making a constructor then it needs to be the same name as your class, i.e. `Tab` and have no return type.

So you would need to add:

```
public Tab() {
    // initialization code here
}
```

You're constructor will run whenever you create a new instance of that class. You want to use it to initialize all of your variables.

```
Tab t = new Tab(); // Constructor runs
```

Edit:

You're main method uses class `Board` but you have given us a class called `Tab`. I can assume that you really want class Board so you should change all `Tab` to `Board` in the above example, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thnaks, the problem was the constructor had void in it so I deleted void to create a proper constructor and it worked.